# https requests using a proxy

Tags: ssl, proxy

Let's say you want to perform an https request to a certain website but you have a proxy on the middle.

The aforesaid proxy doesn't look into the request but just relay all the traffic to the actual HTTPS server after the user-agent has used the HTTP CONNECT method (as in http://www.web-cache.com/Writings/Internet-Drafts/draft-luotonen-web-proxy-tunneling-01.txt).

Now my question is the following: after the proxy opens a SSL connection to the destination webserver, should it also upgrade the socket which handles the connection with the client to SSL as well? And if so, how would it forward packets to the server without sniffing the actual content?

What I mean here is that if the proxy actually reads data from SSL client socket and forwards them to SSL server socket, the data will be not encrypted to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proxy has a plaintext connection open to the client, via which it received the CONNECT command. It opens a plaintext connection to the server. Thereafter it just copies bytes in both directions. The bytes coming from both client and server are SSL, so this works without the proxy knowing what's inside the ciphertext.

Comment: Just a small note: I'd say not "plaintext" but "opaque data" as plaintext assumes readability.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp I disagree. There are two kinds of TCP connections from the OP's point of view: plaintext (no SSL) and ciphertext (SSL).

Comment: That's from subjective point of view :). In reality everything after CONNECT request itself is treated as opaque data (RFC 2817, section 8.2).

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Certainly, that's what I said. The proxy just copies bytes, it doesn't care what's in them.